# PHP check if uploaded text file contain regex

Tags: php, regex

I have **test.txt** file and I upload and read it using PHP.

## Upload Code and read code

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //GET FILE
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    //READ FILE CONTENT AND PUT IT TO STRING
    $read_file = file_get_contents($file);
}
```

And everything words perfectly..

## What this file contains

`if ( ) { int myVariable = 1254 ; //this is my comment }`

This test.txt file that I uploaded contain this line of code..

## What I am trying to do:

I want after reading this file to get this result:

```
One Identifier Found: myVariable
One Keyword Found: if
One Number Found: 1254
```

## What I have tried:

I have tried to explode this file and use regex to compare each word in this file

`$read_file_array = explode(" ", $read_file);`

## Problem is

I want to read the whole file and get the same results without exploding the file depends on spaces.
Because the file may not contain spaces.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a job for a regexp, it is a job for a parser, such as [this](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a complex problem. You're basically trying to create a programming language parser. You need to absolutely define what fits into each of the categories you are trying to find results for:

> ## What I am trying to do:
>
> I want after reading this file to get this result:
>
> ```
> One Identifier Found: myVariable
> One Keyword Found: if
> One Number Found: 1254
> ```

## How do you recognise each of your "types" of result?

Set this out and you can use this to define a regex rule. For example in PHP identifier variables are `$<name>` so you can do a regex something like `'/($[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*)/i'` which would be:

- Find a dollar sign followed by any a-z character 1 or more times, followed by an a-z or 0-9 characters zero or more times. Case insensitively.

I can't define your keyword search because you need to first define what a keyword actually is. Is `Sausage` a keyword? Why? How is this information obtained?

To find the number you can do something like check for the value is after a certain character, such as equal sign `'\s*=\s*(\d+)'` will seach for and find a possible space, with a equals, with another possible space followed but 1 or more digits.

---

I think you should go away and read up documents and books and online liteature about how Regex works and the logic processes that regex goes through in order to best set your criteria to fit what regex can and can not do.